# Disable GDB breaking on x86 exceptions

Tags: c, x86, gdb, gdbserver, bochs

I'm using gdb with bochs-gdb to debug a virtual memory implementation I am writing. Every time an exception 14 (page fault) is thrown gdb breaks on the handler for the exception. Is there any way I can disable this behavior so that gdb doesn't break on x86 exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop
```

GDB will not stop for page fault but will still print a message. You can also add noprint.

Source:

> "If you don't want GDB to stop for page faults, then issue the command
>   handle SIGSEGV nostop. GDB will still print a message for every page
>   fault, but it will not come back to a command prompt." [link](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3204/fall2007/pintos/doc/pintos_10.html)

Comment: This seems like it is a step in the right direction but your suggestion doesn't work. It isn't a segfault that I'm experiencing (what causes sigsegv to be sent) its a *page* fault.

Comment: @Jon This is wired, I thought that page fault results in segmentation faults and the linked page confirms my thought. However, this is not the case. Searching around it seems that "page faults can result in a segmentation fault or bus error"( and maybe also in other signals?). You can try to handle SIGBUS instead of SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Jon and terence: A segfault is one kind of page fault: A memory reference to a virtual address that isn't in the page table.  However, a segfault (i.e. the kernel delivering a SIGSEGV) only happens when the kernel decides that the virtual address in question *shouldn't* be added to the process's page table.  Other kinds of page faults are handled by one of: paging in the page from disk, doing the actual copy part of copy-on-write shared memory, (something else I'm forgetting).  So the answer you need will be specific to bochs-gdb.